# Using reflection to call a static method on a generic class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a generic class with a non generic static method that performs some operations on the type in question.

```
class MyClass<T> {  
  static List<T> _listOfStuff;

  public static void DoX() { _listOfStuff.Clear(); }
}
```

Rather than writing the code below, I'd like to use reflection and loop over the generic  types and calling DoX().

Keep in mind that the list of types could grow in the future and that MyClass could be used by developers external to the assembly where this code is maintained. I need an automated way to get a `Type[]` array of `int`, `string`, `TypeX`.

```
MyClass<int>.DoX();
MyClass<string>.DoX();
MyClass<TypeX>.DoX();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by “registered”? Why would you need any such list?

Comment: My apologies, I'm not sure what the right terminology is, but rather than specifying a type, I'd like to be able to call DoX() on all types that the class is aware of at run time.

Comment: There is no such thing. The class isn't aware of any types. If you want to get all the type parameters that were ever used in the current program, maybe you want to use the static constructor.

Comment: Well it sort of is. The runtime is well aware of the generic type parameters that are "in use" for this class so I'm simply looking for that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that this is a very weird thing to do. If you want to perform some cleanup, you might consider using non-static classes, or something else. Again, this really does smell of bad design to me, but I can't advise you any better way, because I still have no idea *why* are you trying to do this.

If you're sure you want to do this, there doesn't seem to be a way to get a list of all used types directly. But you can keep a list of all used constructed types in some other non-generic type and add to it from the static constructor.

But if all you want to do is to call `DoX()` for all types, you don't actually need a list of types, you can use a list of delegates to `DoX()` for all used types. That could look something like this:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        MyClass.DoXDelegates.Add(DoX);
    }

    public static void DoX() { /* whatever */ }
}

static class MyClass
{
    private static readonly List<Action> s_DoXDelegates = new List<Action>();
    internal static List<Action> DoXDelegates
    {
        get { return s_DoXDelegates; }
    }

    internal static void DoXForAll()
    {
        foreach (var doXDelegate in DoXDelegates)
            doXDelegate();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to know how other developers will use my library. The problem is, I don't know before hand what the generic type parameters will be, I just need to know which ones are being used on the class.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to know that? Maybe there is some better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: That still doesn't explain *why* do you want to do that. Could you tell us that?

Comment: I want my library to be flexible enough to be used with custom classes written by other developers. Because this static method performs operations on the generic type, I'd like to perform a batch operation on all the generic types that could be in use. For my batch opereation, I'd like to call DoX() on all generic types.

Comment: But why do you think you need to perform “batch operations”? That doesn't make much sense to me. Don't you just want to do some initialization for every type parameter that is used? You could use a static constructor for that. What exactly is `DoX()` supposed to do?

Comment: It does "stuff" to a generic collection List<T> maintained via a static variable in MyClass.

Comment: I don't really need to know *what* it does, but it would be very useful if you told me *why* do you want to do it. And you still didn't explain that.

Comment: Constructing a list of delegates should solve the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if you've just got a static list of the types (warning - not compile checked):

```
Type[] types = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(TypeX) }:

Type myClass = typeof(MyClass<>);

foreach (Type t in types) {
    Type genMyClass = myClass.MakeGenericType(t);
    genMyClass.InvokeMember("DoX", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null);
}
```